# How to get objects of used Rack middleware running in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, middleware

I'm using Rack middleware that accepts some configuration that I need to change at run time. So I need the instance of its class that's currently in memory. Is there a way to do obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow an other way instead.

If you are using Rails 3, you can write the Rack middleware so that it accesses the shared application configuration available at `Rails::Application.config`.
Otherwise, no matter which is your Rails version, you can use a configuration library (such as the `simple_config` gem) and keep the current configuration value in memory so that the Middleware can access it.

Last but not least, remember that Rack has a `Rack::Config` middleware that you can adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In this case I'm on Rails 2.3. Seems like I'd need to fork the middleware gem to use Rack::Config.